# Packaging a C# MVC4 Web app as a standalone desktop app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow package an ASP MVC4 web application (that would normally run on an IIS server+SQLLite) as a standalone desktop application?

As a result, I could distribute a single executable to be run on a desktop computer that displays the URL to which the user would then navigate using her local browser.

I read about Hostable Web Core but for some reason it seems to be tied to IIS7 which I do not want to. Anything IIS8+ or even simply .NET 4.X based is required.

Comment: Starting with next version of ASP.NET MVC you should be able to self host web applications inside a console app or windows service via OWIN (like you can do now with Web API).

Comment: Hi Marcel, do you have additiona info on which version of ASP.NET MVC, dates, any documentation?

Comment: I do not have release dates, but you can have a look here: http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/overview

Comment: You question sounds interesting to me, however I am not sure I understood the idea. Do you want the web app to be hosted on the machine where you run the executable?

Comment: SBirthare, yes, it only needs to be available to the user executing the EXE, no network accessibility is required.